# Which abilities used can be seen (or heard) in the fog of war ?

Tags: league-of-legends

Some of the abilities can be see if you move the camera to the area, even there is no vision (in the fog of war or in a bush).

I know about :

- Shaco's Decieve
- Twisted Fate's Destiny
- Teleport

Is there a list of other abilities ? And are there some of them is just a bug ?

Comment: Well, I do know that you can see someone warding nearby, but that probably isn't what you are looking for.

Comment: Hmm it's a really good and interesting question but I think it's too broad. Also it's a duplicate :/